# crossdomain not allow in openfire for http request

Tags: openfire

I try to connect by **jquery library** to **openfire chat server** on `domain:7070/http-bind`

Openfire not allow me to connect and in result

> "giving error Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy
>   disallows reading the remote resource at
>   http://192.168.10.125:7070/http-bind. (Reason: CORS request failed)."

Answer (score 0):

Ankit, in your openfire admin console, check whether you have enabled CORS option.

In admin console, Go to Server Settings ---> Http Binding

Also attaching a snap for your reference.
[image]

Comment: Yes i have added this in my server and also created the crossdomain .xml for allowing but still have the save problem .